# ! Undefined control sequence. l.25 \tbl {Optimal geometrical parameters of asymmetrical multiple open slot

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}[pt]
\tbl{Optimal geometrical parameters of asymmetrical multiple open slot loaded microstrip antenna.}
{\begin{tabular}{@{}|c|ccc|cccccccccc@{}} \toprule
Parameter & $L_p$ & $W_p$ & $G_1$ & $P_2$ & $G_3$ & $P_4$& $G_5$ & $P_6$ & $P_7$ & $P_8$ & $X_f$ & $P_{10}$ & $W_f$    \\ \colrule
Value (mm) &37 & 40 & 10 & 4.5 & 7.5 & 2 & 7 & 19.5 & 10.5 & 8.3 & 7 & 4 & 24\\ \\
Parameter & $L_s$ & $W_s$ & $L_g$ & $W_g$ & $P_9$ & $P_{11}$ & $G_1$ & $G_2$ & $P_3$ & $G_4$ & $P_5$ & $G_6$ &   \\ \colrule
Value (mm) & 39  & 45 & 39 & 45 & 6 & 7.35 & 2 & 12.5  & 6 & 12.5 & 21 & 5.5 &  \\
 \botrule
\end{tabular} }
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\tbl` is not a standard command. Presumably whatever documentation that you saw that suggested this command also showed how to define it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You did not include the start of your document. The command `\tbl` is only available in some document classes, like those from the AMS. If you need further advice, please add the preamble of your document, from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`.